# How do I reference the string in a array of strings?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following:

```
var tags = ["Favorite", "Starred", "High Rated"];

for (var tag in tags) {
    console.log(tag);
}
```

Output is

```
0
1
2
```

I'd like it to output:

```
Favorite
Starred
High Rated
```

How do I do this? Thanks.

Comment: `console.log(tags[tag])`

Comment: @onetrickpony this worked. Please submit as answer and I'll mark as correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Itearting over an array:

That's an array of strings, don't use `for..in`, use the vanilla `for` loop:

```
var tags = ["Favorite", "Starred", "High Rated"];
for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) { // proper way to iterate an array
    console.log(tags[i]);
}
```

Output:

```
Favorite
Starred
High Rated
```

### Proper usage of `for..in`:

It is meant for object's properties, like:

```
var tags2 = {"Favorite": "some", "Starred": "stuff", "High Rated": "here"};
for (var tag in tags2) { // enumerating objects properties
    console.log("My property: " + tag +"'s value is " +tags2[tag]);
}
```

Output:

```
My property: Favorite's value is some
My property: Starred's value is stuff
My property: High Rated's value is here
```

### Side effects of `for..in` with arrays:

Don't take my word for it, let's see why not use it: `for..in` in arrays can have side effects. Take a look:

```
var tags3 = ["Favorite", "Starred", "High Rated"];
tags3.gotcha = 'GOTCHA!'; // not an item of the array

// they can be set globally too, affecting all arrays without you noticing:
Array.prototype.otherGotcha = "GLOBAL!";

for (var tag in tags3) {
    console.log("Side effect: "+ tags3[tag]);
}
```

Output:

```
Side effect: Favorite
Side effect: Starred
Side effect: High
Side effect: GOTCHA!
Side effect: GLOBAL!
```

**[See a demo fiddle for these codes.](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/XkWMb/3)**

Comment: +1 for object's properties usage

Answer (score 0):

Using `in` in `for` loops in JavaScript is not like `:` in Java or foreach in other languages - instead of providing reference to the element, it provides its index. 
If you use a framework like jQuery, there is a method - `$.each` which gives access to the element (not only the index) via callback when iterating:

```js
var a = ["Favorite", "Starred", "High Rated"];
$.each ( a, function ( index, data ) 
{
   console.log ( data );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why would you use jQuery just to iterate over an array?

Comment: That's not true.  `for..in` does NOT return the index, but the properties of the object. If you use an array the properties are it's indexes, but if you use an object you'll get a different output (e.g: `var person = { name: 'John', age: 25 }; for(var c in person ) { console.log(c); }`). I also wouldn't use jQuery for iterating through a list. Using native javascript is way more [performatic](http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loop/65) .