# How to simplify nested loops and conditions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Given a JS as follows:

```js
for (c in chars) {
    for (i in data) {
        if (data[i].item === chars[c]) {
            // do my stuff;
        }
        else { /* do something else */}
    }
}
```

and data such:

```js
var chars = [ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C' ];
var data = [
    {'item':'A', 'rank': '1'}, 
    {'item':'B', 'rank': '2'}, 
    {'item':'C', 'rank': '3'}
    // no duplicate
];
```

Is there a simpler syntax to express that rather than nested `for` loops and inner conditions?

I try to match two datasets, more precisely to use `chars`'s keys to iterate `data` and find values.

Comment: Wait, are you trying to [iterate over an array with `for in`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17499001/1850609)?

Comment: @acdcjunior It works. Just remember that the iteration variable is set to the indexes, not the values (it's not like PHP `foreach`).

Comment: I try to match two datasets, more precisely to use `chars`'s keys to iterate `data` and find values.

Comment: @Hugolpz you can use something like this: `data.forEach(function(i){if(c.indexOf(i.item)!=-1){}else{}});`

Comment: @Barmar What works? The `for in` for arrays? If so, I'm not saying it doesn't, I'm say one shouldn't, as it can screw your code up.

Comment: @Hugolpz what's the intended platform? What browsers? Just the newest?

Comment: With the example data there only needs to be one loop as c and I are the same value when their  values match. The question needs a representative example.

Comment: Will there ever be duplicate chars? Or dupicate data items? Or both? If so, should there be multiple positives for the dupes?

Comment: Are you forced to have your data in that format, or can you use an map with the obvious key?

Comment: So you just need a map of letters to rank. Why not just do a map as suggested by @DaveNewton?

Comment: acdc: for a web app.
Crazy: for duplicata, I clarified in my question.
@AD7:
#Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/bysBH/4/ (the question stays to make a simplier JS)

Comment: @Hugolpz Web app, ok, but, what browsers do you wish to support? The latest have many possibly useful array functions. But if you wish to support olders, you'd have less options.

Comment: Chrome and modern browsers. I don't bother with dinos.

Comment: But the `chars` represents the `textarea` input, right? So it doesn't matter if there's duplictes. An `"A"` will always look up `"A"` in the map, and get `"easy"`. http://jsfiddle.net/bysBH/5/

Comment: ...or like this: http://jsfiddle.net/bysBH/7/

Comment: Check [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/bysBH/8/) out. It uses [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2FReduce) ([IE9 and later](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Array.prototype.reduce)) and converts your `da` object into a `da2` map for quicker acessing.

Comment: @acdcjunior: wow, a bit high level for me (beginner).

Comment: @CrazyTrain's fiddle nice too, and easier for me !

Comment: @CrazyTrain: While it doesn't really answer to the nested loops simplification, I will use your witty code.

Comment: @Hugolpz: Yeah, I think your nested loops are about as simple as they can get. In this specific case, a key/value map is definitely the way to go. Will be faster too.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (chars.indexOf(data[i].item) != -1) {
        // Do something
    } else {
        // Do something else
    }
}
```

However, if `chars` is large, I would create an object whose keys are the elements of `chars` and use `if (chars_obj[data[i].item])`. This is more efficient than searching an array every time.

Comment: with a sidenote: `Array.indexOf` isn't supported in older browsers.

Comment: I don't know what OP specifically needs, but this will be a little different if there's more than one of the same letter in the `chars` Array.

Comment: @Barmar this is not what the OP wants. With the OP example, 15 functions are executed (either my stuff or something else).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to simplifying the code would be to encapsulate and abstract it away into a utility that accepts callbacks, than reuse that whenever needed, like so:

```js
// definition
function eachChar(onMatch, onMismatch) {
    for (c in chars) {
        for (i in data) {
            if (data[i].item === chars[c]) {
                typeof onMatch === 'function' && onMatch(); 
            } else {
                typeof onMismatch === 'function' && onMismatch(); 
            }
        }
    }
}

// usage examples
eachChar(function() {
    // do something when it's a match
});
eachChar(function() {
    // do something when it's a match
}, function() {
    // do something else when it's not
});
```

See a [**live demo on jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/J8vUr/2/).

---

As a sidenote, you would want to explicitly declare variables used as loop indexes, as to not exposing them in an outer scope (e.g. the *global* scope):

```js
// that:
for (c in chars) {
    for (i in data) {

// would become this:
for (var c in chars) {
    for (var i in data) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged your question jquery, you could use a jquery solution:

```js
$.each(chars, function (cndx, chr) {
    $.each(data, function (dndx, datum) {
        if (datum.item === chr) {
            // do my stuff;
        } else {
            /* do something else */
        }
    }
});
```

Not any more succinct, but at least you don't have to index.

Comment: It's not really simpler, only camouflage.

Comment: Not entirely true -- indexing is often a vector for subtle bugs.